# && statement with if condition in jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

If condition alone is working but when I used and operation is not working properly. just one of them it becomes true code is working. also, it takes the value properly from inputs.

```
  <! HTML Code !>
  <form id="myform" action="new.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" 
   autocomplete="off">
 <h4 style="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;">ID</h4>
 <input class="form-control" name="id" id="id"  style="margin-left:100px; 
 background: url(icons/id.png) no-repeat scroll 5px 5px; padding-left:35px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; width:360px; margin-top:-40px;"  
  type="text" placeholder="Your ID Here">
 <h4 style="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;">Name</h4>
 <input class="form-control" name="name" id="newname"  style="margin- 
 left:100px; width:360px; background: url(icons/name2.png) no-repeat scroll 
 5px 5px; padding-left:35px; border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; margin- 
 top:-40px;"  type="text" placeholder="Your Name Here">
 </form>
  <! Script Code !>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $("#myform").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id=$("#id").val();
        var name=$("#newname").val();
        if( name=="" && id=="")
        {
            sweatalertInfo();
        }else{
        $.ajax({
            url: "newteam.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                sweatalertPass();
                //alert(data);
                $('form').trigger("reset");
                },
            error: function (data) {
            }
          });
        }
       }));
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: So you want to return `true` if both conditions are met or if one of them are met?

Comment: I don't think there's any issue with your code. How are you triggering `submit` event?

Comment: I want return both condition must become true

Answer (score 0):

If you need both not empty strings, you need to take a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) instead of a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()).

The result is an alert if `name` is empty or `id` is empty or both.

```
if (name == "" || id == "") {
```

A short approach with strings could be to use the truty/falsy value of the string directly with logical AND and a [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) for the expression.

```
if (!(name && id)) {
```

Comment: I don't want to use OR operation, I want to use And operation